# How can I display an ImageResource during a drag-n-drop using dataTransfer.setDragImage()?

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop a cell in GWT and customize the drag image using dataTransfer.setDragImage().
My image is an ImageResource and here is what I have:

Here is how I construct my "draggable cell"

```
public CheckBoxDragCell(boolean dependsOnSelection, boolean handlesSelection,ImageResource icon) {
          this(dependsOnSelection,handlesSelection);
          this.icon = AbstractImagePrototype.create(icon);
    }
```

Here is the eventHandler for the drag:

```
@Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, Boolean value, 
      NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Boolean> valueUpdater) {
    String type = event.getType();

    boolean enterPressed = "keydown".equals(type) && event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER;

    if ("dragstart".equals(type)){
        DataTransfer dataTransfer = event.getDataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.setData("text", String.valueOf(context.getIndex()));

        if (icon != null){
            Image image = icon.createImage();
            image.setVisible(true);
            dataTransfer.setDragImage(ImageElement.as(image.getElement()), 25, 15);
        }
```

But somehow the image never shows up. To debug, I created a dialogbox and displayed the image there when the eventHandler is called and sure enough it show up there... but not when I call the dataTransfer.setDragImage(....) function.
Any help will be enormously appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the image did not show up in the first case is because the `ImageElement` is not added to the DOM.

Try adding the `ImageElement.as(image.getElement())` to the DOM, then it would show.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it could be an issue of browser support?

I've tried this HTML5 native drag and drop demo: http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

The custom drag image part of it didn't work for me (Chrome 17.0.932.0 dev-m).

Comment: Drag and drop work for me... It is just that I am unable to customize the ghost drag image

Comment: @daghan That's what I said. It might not be supported. Did the ghost image demo work for you at the link above?